# AsyncStorage is per device?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

My question is if the AsyncStorage is per device?
I mean when a few different users entry to my app and each one of them set for the same key but different value so each one of them going to have his own storage(his own value)?

And how the data in AsyncStorage may be deleted? Only if the user clean the data for this app or delete/update the app?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The same `AsyncStorage` store is reused for the same app on the device.  If you are going to have more than one user on the same app/device, you should consider appending a user-specific prefix to each key. (e.g. "LastLoginDate-Mike")

There is no global way to delete all the data in `AsyncStorage` other than deleting the app.  Individual items can be deleted by using `AsyncStorage.removeItem`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer... so if I have many users and each user has his own device so I can use with the same key right? Bc it’s local variable...